# Django Form ChoiceField range(): 'int' object not iterable

Tags: django, forms, range, choicefield

```
from django import forms

class SignUpForm(forms.Form):
    birth_day = forms.ChoiceField(choices=range(1,32))
```

I'm getting "Caught TypeError while rendering: 'int' object is not iterable".
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#field-choices says the choices argument takes iterables such as a list or tuple.

http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range says range() creates a list.

Why am I getting an error?

I tried converting the list to str using map() but received different errors.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> ... says the choices argument takes iterables such as a list or tuple.

No, it says it takes an iterable *of 2-tuples*.

> An iterable (e.g., a list or tuple) of 2-tuples to use as choices for this field.

```
birth_day = forms.ChoiceField(choices=((str(x), x) for x in range(1,32)))
```

Comment: Works, looks like I need to be careful when reading. Solution has one extra left parentheses that needs to be removed.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: is there any reason why you use generator instead list or tuple? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940293/why-is-there-no-tuple-comprehension-in-python

Comment: @noisy: Mostly force of habit, but there's no need for the full data structure in the bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 tuples. Use zip built-in function for the same 2 tuples

```
from django import forms


class SignUpForm(forms.Form):

    birth_day = models.IntegerField(choices=list(zip(range(1, 32), range(1, 32))), unique=True)
```

Remember (1,32) will create from 1 to 31 !