# IDLE (Python) does not display the type

Tags: python-3.x, python-idle

For some reason IDLE is not displaying the `type` of `tuple i`. Any idea what's wrong here?

[image: IDLE (Python)]

```
>>> d = {"a":"apple","b":"boy","c":"cat"}
>>> d
{'a': 'apple', 'b': 'boy', 'c': 'cat'}
>>> t = ((k,v) for k,v in d.items())
>>> t
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0237C558>
>>> for i in t: print(i)

('a', 'apple')
('b', 'boy')
('c', 'cat')
>>> for i in t: print(type(i))

>>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generators are iterators but they do not store data into memory like lists so they can be accessed only once.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained) is a great explanation about generators.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940293/why-is-there-no-tuple-comprehension 8) My intent was to create a tuple comp'n

Answer (score 2):

You can consume *Iterator / Generator* only one time.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> g = iter(a)
>>> for i in g: print i
...
1
2
3
>>> for i in g: print i
...
>>>
```

Comment: >>> a = [1,2]
>>> for i in a: print(i) # 1 2
>>> for i in a: print(i) # 1 2
How is this different?

Comment: @GLES, `for i in a: ..` is similar to `for i in iter(a): ..` which create new iterator.  If you do another `for i in a`, it will create another iterator instead of using already consumed one.