# Python: why does list comprehension produce a generator?

Tags: python, generator, list-comprehension

```
a=[['1','3','2'],['11','22','33']]
k = [(float(a[i][j]) for j in range(0,3)) for i in range(0,2)]
>>> print k
[<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f1a9d568f50>, <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f1a9d568fa0>]
```

but I want to get [(1,3,2),(11,22,33)]
 why does list comprehension produce a generator?

Comment: Because `(float(a[i][j]) for j in range(0,3))` is a generator expression

Comment: Because you put a generator expression in it? That's what the `(... for j in range(0, 3))` *does* there.

Comment: [<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f1a9d568f50>, ...] actually is a _LIST_ of generators.

Comment: technically it is a list .... a list of generators.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a [generator expression](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) (`(x for x in ...)`) inside a list comprehension (`[x for x in ...]`). This will return a list of generator objects. Change the code like so

```
a = [['1','3','2'],['11','22','33']]
k = [[float(a[i][j]) for j in range(0,3)] for i in range(0,2)]

print(k)
# [[1.0, 3.0, 2.0], [11.0, 22.0, 33.0]]
```

Comment: is it possible to get [(1,3,2),(11,22,33)]?

Comment: Yes. You can wrap the list comprehension in a tuple call so `[tuple([...]) for ...]`. However, I'd suggest you look up Martijn Pieter's answer as he explains how you can get what you want in a much neater fashion :)

Answer (score 6):

You are using a generator expression in your list comprehension expression:

```
(float(a[i][j]) for j in range(0,3))
```

If you wanted that to execute like a list comprehension, make *that* a list comprehension *too*:

```
[[float(a[i][j]) for j in range(3)] for i in range(2)]
```

If you need those to be tuples, then you'll have to explicitly call `tuple()`:

```
[tuple(float(a[i][j]) for j in range(3)) for i in range(2)]
```

The `tuple()` callable will drive the generator expression to produce a tuple of those values. There is [no such thing as a tuple comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940293/why-is-there-no-tuple-comprehension-in-python), otherwise.

Rather than use ranges, you can loop over `a` and the nested lists *directly*:

```
[tuple(float(v) for v in nested) for nested in a]
```

Demo:

```
>>> a=[['1','3','2'],['11','22','33']]
>>> [tuple(float(v) for v in nested) for nested in a]
[(1.0, 3.0, 2.0), (11.0, 22.0, 33.0)]
```