# List comprehension of tuple gets me a generator - why and how to modify?

Tags: python, generator, list-comprehension

I am going through the exercises of this site https://anandology.com/python-practice-book/working-with-data.html when I tried to recreate the zip function through list comprehension. 
Now I created this function. But instead of getting a list I get a generator :-(

```
def zipp (liste1,liste2):
    length= len(liste1)
    zipped=[]
    [zipped.append(tuple(liste1[i], liste2[i]) for i in range(length))]
    return zipped
```

I searched a little in here and found this: 
[Python: why does list comprehension produce a generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27968339/python-why-does-list-comprehension-produce-a-generator)

Accordingly I used the "tuple" statement already but to no awail.

I have no idea why I get a generator even with the tuple() inserted. 
So my questions:

1. why?
2. What do I need to change or where can I read/hear more to get "enlightened" myself?
3. How could I use the generator to get the result? (or where can I read about this?)

Thanks.

edit: The result I expect is list of tuple with member of each list in it. This I what I should get:

zipp([1, 2, 3], ["a", "b", "c"])
-> [(1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c")]

Comment: This is abusing a side-effect of list comprehensions; this is not considered good practice. You're using the list comprehension to drive what should be a `for` loop.

Comment: You should definitely never use a list comprehension for side-effects. *especially* not in this case, were your list-comprehension should be doing the appending...

Comment: It's bending my mind a little to understand exactly what you want your output to look like. Can you please show what you are expecting? The outer list comp is throwing me

Comment: Anyway, `tuple(liste1[i], liste2[i]) for i in range(length)` is a generator expression, which is sort of like a list comprehension that creates a generator instead. So don't use that.

Comment: @roganjosh they are trying to re-implement `zip`.

Comment: can't you use `list(zip())` ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I think the point is to re-implement `zip` as an exercise

Comment: in that case the length is incorrect. Should be min of both lengths.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre well, that's definitely one issue.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga mm, so the outer list isn't really supposed to be substituting a `for`, that's what the (erroneous) gen expr is for. Ok, I wasn't seeing it

Comment: @roganjosh ah jeez, yeah didn't even notice that myself, this is simply a call to `.append(<gen expr>)` wrapped in a list: `[ ]`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre  It is an exercise. And yes, you are right I should check for the length f both lists.

Comment: @roganjosh Thanks for the feedback. You are right a for loop would be the way I'd take normally. But the exercise was to use a list comprehension. And this was the best I could come up. 
But one important question for me for better understanding: what is meant by "side-effect of list comprehensions"?

Comment: List comprehensions can mutate mutable objects as though the list comprehension was a regular `for` loop. So, I could use a list comprehension like so; `my_list = []; [my_list.append(x) for x in range(5)]`. In this instance, the list comprehension does not generate its own list at all. Instead, it modifies a different list altogether. This is considered a _side effect_; the correct approach would be `my_list = [x for x in range(5)]`.. Silly example, but hopefully illustrates the point.

Comment: Sorry for the multiple edits, on a phone. Obviously the best way in my example would just be `my_list = list(range(5))` but I'm shooting for an example with minimal fighting against autocorrect to illustrate my point

Comment: Ok. After reading it a few times I think I got the point. Thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 2):

you're putting a *generator* in your object:

```
tuple(liste1[i], liste2[i]) for i in range(length)
```

(and `tuple` doesn't work too, just remove it....)

(and don't use comprehensions for side effects)

The best way would be to rewrite it completely using a list comprehension which actually *returns* something, as list comprehensions are supposed to, taking the min of both lengths to fully emulate `zip`:

```
def zipp (liste1,liste2):
    return [(liste1[i], liste2[i]) for i in range(min(len(liste1),len(liste2)))]
```

classic loop version (no comprehensions)

```
def zipp (liste1,liste2):
   result = []
   for i in range(min(len(liste1),len(liste2))):
       result.append((liste1[i], liste2[i]))
   return result
```

of course this is nothing else than `list(zip(liste1,liste2))`  (forcing iteration on `zip`)

Comment: I would just add the straight-forward for-loop way as well, just to illustrate what list-comprehensions are actually doing

Comment: Your zipp solution is actually what I was looking for! Thanks. Btw, I fixed mine too, but it got even uglier: `[zipped.append([tuple([liste1[i], liste2[i]]) for i in range(length)])]` or without tuple:`zipped.append([(liste1[i], liste2[i]) for i in range(length)])`

Comment: don't append to a list with a list, extend it.

Answer (score 1):

trying to answer your questions...

> 1.- why?

A: As many have mention, you return the `zipped` list as a list generators within the list comprehension `[zipped.append(tuple(liste1[i], liste2[i]) for i in range(length))]`, not a nice way of doing by the way. that's why you get those generators.

> 2.- What do I need to change or where can I read/hear more to get "enlightened" myself?

A: If you still want to do that way, you only have to append the two items, by moving the parenthesis and removing the tuple function, like so:

```
def zipp (liste1, liste2):
    length = len(liste1)
    zipped = []
    [zipped.append( (liste1[i], liste2[i]) ) for i in range(length) ]  # not the best way, but still works. This created list is never used.
    return zipped
```

then it's possible to return the list

```
zipp([1,2,3], ['a','b','c'])
```

Note that this asumes both list have same length. Otherwise you have to choose  one (like you are doing) or finding the minimum of both lengths (it's also posible to choose the longest and fill with whatever it's needed):

`min(len(liste1), len(liste2))`

> 3.- How could I use the generator to get the result?

A: For it to be a generator you need to yield the nedeed value:

```
def zipp2 (liste1,liste2):
    i = 0
    minval = min(len(liste1), len(liste2))
    while i< minval:
        yield (liste1[i], liste2[i])
        i += 1

# call the function generator
gen = zipp2([1,2,3], ['a','b','c'])
print(gen)
for p in gen:
    print(p)
```

and get the results...

```
<generator object zipp2 at 0x7fe46bef3db0>
(1, 'a')
(2, 'b')
(3, 'c')
```

Comment: Thanks for the zipp2 snippet. But my question regarded my accidental generator generation. I thought there might be a way to get real values by using this accidental generator?

Comment: as @Jean-François Fabre's comment says: don't append it, extend it.
like so: `zipped.extend( [(liste1[i], liste2[i]) for i in range(length)] )`

Comment: extend() method takes an interable as argument, so it also works without the square brackets: `zipped.extend( (liste1[i], liste2[i]) for i in range(length) )`

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I didn't now this method yet.