# Generators vs List Comprehension performance in Python

Tags: python, profiling, generator, list-comprehension

Currently I was learning about generators and list comprehension, and messing around with the profiler to see about performance gains stumbled into this cProfile of a sum of prime numbers in a large range using both.

I can see that in the generator the :1 genexpr as cumulative time way shorter than in its list counterpart, but the second line is what baffles me. Is doing a call which I think is the check for number is prime, but then isn't supposed to be another :1 module in the list comprehension?

Am I missing something in the profile?

```
In [8]: cProfile.run('sum((number for number in xrange(9999999) if number % 2 == 0))')
         5000004 function calls in 1.111 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
  5000001    0.760    0.000    0.760    0.000 <string>:1(<genexpr>)
        1    0.000    0.000    1.111    1.111 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.351    0.351    1.111    1.111 {sum}



In [9]: cProfile.run('sum([number for number in xrange(9999999) if number % 2 == 0])')
         3 function calls in 1.123 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    1.075    1.075    1.123    1.123 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.048    0.048    0.048    0.048 {sum}
```

Comment: I don't think they're prime, only even.

Comment: why are you expecting another `:1 module`?

Comment: Isn't the surprising thing here that 5000001 more function calls are made in one than in another? That is exactly the number of times `next` would be called.

Comment: In Python 2 you are not going to get any additional line for a list comprehension, but in Python 3 you will because now to make it similar to a generator expression an additional code object(`<listcomp>`) is created for a List comprehension as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30097520/846892

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I meant even. Brain freeze. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all the calls are to `next`(or `__next__` in Python 3) method of the generator object not for some even number check.

In Python 2 you are not going to get any additional line for a list comprehension(LC) because LC are not creating any object, but in Python 3 you will because now to make it similar to a generator expression an additional code object(`<listcomp>`) is created for a LC as well.

```
>>> cProfile.run('sum([number for number in range(9999999) if number % 2 == 0])')
         5 function calls in 1.751 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    1.601    1.601    1.601    1.601 <string>:1(<listcomp>)
        1    0.068    0.068    1.751    1.751 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    1.751    1.751 {built-in method exec}
        1    0.082    0.082    0.082    0.082 {built-in method sum}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}

>>> cProfile.run('sum((number for number in range(9999999) if number % 2 == 0))')
         5000005 function calls in 2.388 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
  5000001    1.873    0.000    1.873    0.000 <string>:1(<genexpr>)
        1    0.000    0.000    2.388    2.388 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    2.388    2.388 {built-in method exec}
        1    0.515    0.515    2.388    2.388 {built-in method sum}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

The number of calls are different though 1(LC) compared to 5000001 in generator expression, this is most because `sum` is consuming the iterator hence has to call its `__next__` method 500000 + 1 times(last 1 is probably for `StopIteration` to end the iteration). For a list comprehension all the magic happens inside its code object where the `LIST_APPEND` helps it in appending items one by one to the list, i.e no visible calls for `cProfile`.

Comment: You could then said that the benefit of using a generator over a list comprehension, is that at the end of the run you would end with a huge list in memory, which is collected at the end, vs the generator which only access and right away deletes the number? That is the lesson here?

Comment: @cllamach After a particular size yes [<genexpr> will beat list comprehension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11964130/list-comprehension-vs-generator-expressions-weird-timeit-results), and unless we actually need the list there's no need to create one in memory.  `str.join` is one exception that performs well if we feed it a list rather than a <genexpr>. Note that for actual benchmarking you should use `timeit` module not cProfile.