# What is an attribute lookup to list.append?

Tags: python

When considering options for creating lists there are list comprehensions, `list()` constructor, and the `[]` literal syntax.

I found an [article](https://pythonsimplified.com/comprehensive-guide-to-python-list-comprehensions/#What_happens_under_the_hood) where it says that list comprehensions are transformed into functions that call `list.append()` under the hood.

[image: transformation of LC into function equivalent]

So this has given me the impression that `append()` is called on the list upon each iteration through the list, just as say in a similar implementation you could write this in using a `for loop` if you wanted to instead.

However, I've now found a prior [answer here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30096351/are-list-comprehensions-syntactic-sugar-for-listgenerator-expression-in-pyth) which says:

> The list comprehension version takes advantage of the special bytecode
> LIST_APPEND which calls PyList_Append directly for us. Hence it avoids
> an attribute lookup to list.append and a function call at the Python
> level.

So, when you write a list comprehension such as the above squares example, is it calling `append()` on each iteration, or not?

What does an attribute lookup to list.append mean, versus the actual c level call to list.append()?

Comment: It isn't clear how this question is anything other than a duplicate of the question that you link to. You seem to be asking if the accepted answer in that question is valid.

Comment: No, not at all questioning the accepted answer's validity! I've reworded my question since pinning down my confusion.

Comment: When something like "squares.append" in code appears, it always requires to check if "squares" is a list and retrieve the function referenced by the attribute "append" and doing some other things. In a list comprehension the runtime knows it is working on a list and it knows that the "append" method of a list should be used without looking it up.

Comment: When you do something like `some_object.whatever` that is an *attribute lookup*, which require searching for that attribute at runtime. Note, you can accomplish the same thing by using `whatever = some_object.whatever`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the append `append()` method won't be called inside python.

It's been called inside the compiler implicitly:

```py
In [17]: class list2(list):
    ...:     def append(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ...:         print("I have been called")
    ...:         super().append(*args, **kwargs)
    ...: 

In [18]: a = (i for i in range(10))

In [19]: l = list2(a)

In [20]: l
Out[20]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

In [21]: l.append(10)
I have been called

In [22]: l
Out[22]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

I checked the disassembly of its code:

```py
In [28]: def f():
    ...:     return [i for i in range(10)]
    ...: 

In [29]: dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <listcomp> at 0x7f06bf957d60, file "<ipython-input-28-461835cd83dc>", line 2>)
              2 LOAD_CONST               2 ('f.<locals>.<listcomp>')
              4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              8 LOAD_CONST               3 (10)
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 GET_ITER
             14 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             16 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object <listcomp> at 0x7f06bf957d60, file "<ipython-input-28-461835cd83dc>", line 2>:
  2           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    4 FOR_ITER                 4 (to 14)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (i)
              8 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
             10 LIST_APPEND              2
             12 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            2 (to 4)
        >>   14 RETURN_VALUE
```

If you look at the second part, there is disassembly of the object being returned. There is a `FOR_ITER` which is closed with a `JUMP_ABSOLUTE`. The numbers like `(to 4)` are refering where to jump. It's iterating all over, and appending at the same time.

Comment: I also tried to disassemble. With `list()` `LIST_APPEND` is replaced by `POP_TOP`

Answer (score 2):

The `dis` module can be used to inspect the internal python bytecode directly. Here are the two functions (modified slightly to be more self consistent), and the resulting bytecodes that are sent to the python interpreter after they are parsed:

```py
def comprehension():
    squares = [num for num in range(1,11) if num % 2 == 0]
    return squares
    
def loop():
    squares = []
    for num in range(1,11):
        if num % 2 == 0:
            squares.append(num)
    return squares
```

Then calling `dis.dis(comprehension)`:

```
>>> dis(comprehension)
 10           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <listcomp> at 0x0000021EB480BBE0, file "C:\Users\aaron\Documents\scripts\python\untitled2.py", line 10>)
              2 LOAD_CONST               2 ('comprehension.<locals>.<listcomp>')
              4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              8 LOAD_CONST               3 (1)
             10 LOAD_CONST               4 (11)
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             14 GET_ITER
             16 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             18 STORE_FAST               0 (squares)

 11          20 LOAD_FAST                0 (squares)
             22 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object <listcomp> at 0x0000021EB480BBE0, file "C:\Users\aaron\Documents\scripts\python\untitled2.py", line 10>:
 10           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    4 FOR_ITER                20 (to 26)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (num)
              8 LOAD_FAST                1 (num)
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (2)
             12 BINARY_MODULO
             14 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
             16 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             18 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        4
             20 LOAD_FAST                1 (num)
             22 LIST_APPEND              2
             24 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            4
        >>   26 RETURN_VALUE
```

Interpreting this output takes a little practice, but the general flow is that the "list comprehension function" is created first (`MAKE_FUNCTION` jumps down to 2nd "disassembly" block), which takes care of creating a new list `BUILD_LIST`, iterating over an iterator `FOR_ITER`, testing the conditional `POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE`, and (when the conditional is true) directly appending to the list `LIST_APPEND`. After creating this "comprehension function" we return to the main function to create the iterator which is then passed to the function we created. Finally the result gets stored to a variable and that variable is returned.

---

The `loop` function is actually fewer bytecode instructions, but don't necessarily interpret that as being faster or better... some bytecode instructions are more complicated / slower than others. Only actual profiling can actually tell you the difference in speed.

```
>>> dis(loop)
 14           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              2 STORE_FAST               0 (squares)

 15           4 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              8 LOAD_CONST               2 (11)
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             12 GET_ITER
        >>   14 FOR_ITER                26 (to 42)
             16 STORE_FAST               1 (num)

 16          18 LOAD_FAST                1 (num)
             20 LOAD_CONST               3 (2)
             22 BINARY_MODULO
             24 LOAD_CONST               4 (0)
             26 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             28 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       14

 17          30 LOAD_FAST                0 (squares)
             32 LOAD_METHOD              1 (append)
             34 LOAD_FAST                1 (num)
             36 CALL_METHOD              1
             38 POP_TOP
             40 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           14

 18     >>   42 LOAD_FAST                0 (squares)
             44 RETURN_VALUE
```

Following the path of this function is a little bit more straightforward, but the key difference is really that python has to look up the "append" method from "squares" before it can call it, because it doesn't inherently know that "squares" is a list, and therefore can't just call `LIST_APPEND`