# Python accessing tuple index by value

Tags: python, tuples

Let's say I have a tuple that is (4, 5, 6, 7, 8). I want to iterate through it, then each iteration only print the numbers after that index. So like this:

```
for i in tuple:
    #print values to the right of i
```

Example output: 5, 6, 7, 8, 6, 7, 8, 7, 8, 8. Any help? I know how to access a tuple value by its index but not by the reverse.

Answer (score 6):

Do you mean something like this?

```
t = (4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
for i, _ in enumerate(t, 1):
  print(t[i:])

# (5, 6, 7, 8)
# (6, 7, 8)
# (7, 8)
# (8,)
# ()
```

If you want to join them all into an output tuple, the following 1-liner will do it inefficiently:

```
>>> sum((t[i:] for i, _ in enumerate(t, 1)), ())
(5, 6, 7, 8, 6, 7, 8, 7, 8, 8)
```

A more efficient way would be to use `itertools.chain.from_iterable`:

```
tuple(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
    t[i:] for i, _ in enumerate(t, 1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
tuple = (4,5,6,7,8)
z = []
for i in range(len(tuple)):
    for j in tuple[i+1:]:
        z.append(j)
```

output is [5,6,7,8,6,7,8,7,8,8]

Comment: do you mean `z.extend(j)`?  appending will result in a list with tuples as items.

Comment: this is appending the individual items of the tuple, not the tuple itself.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Python documentation, [tuples are immutable objects](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).  So if you want to change the output that you produce each time you iterate through the tuple, you will need to set a new variable in your loop each time.  Something like this:

```
t = (5,6,7,8)
for i,n in enumerate(t):
    tnew = t[i:]
    print tnew
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a list comprehension:

```
t = (4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
>>> [i for n in range(len(t)) for i in t[n+1:]]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 6, 7, 8, 7, 8, 8]
```

Or if you want a tuple, you can use a generator expression ([tuple comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940293/why-is-there-no-tuple-comprehension-in-python)?):

```
>>> tuple(i for n in range(len(t)) for i in t[n+1:])
(5, 6, 7, 8, 6, 7, 8, 7, 8, 8)
```