# Difference in printing tuples and list in python

Tags: python, list, tuples, generator-expression

When I'm changing output type between list and tuple, one is showing output whereas other is just showing location of result. Why does this happen?

```
>>> symbol = '123456789'
>>> (s for s in symbol)
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fc0e9e2fbf8>
>>> [s for s in symbol]
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

Comment: @NedBatchelder And google'ing 'generator object' probably would have sufficed instead of making a post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is there no tuple comprehension in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940293/why-is-there-no-tuple-comprehension-in-python)

Answer (score -1):

`(s for s in symbol)` is generator comprehension. Similar to:

```
symbol = '123456789'
def func():
    for s in symbol:
        yield s

g = func()
print(g)
<generator object func at 0x7ffff7e59410>

print(tuple(g)) 
('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9')
```

If you supply the generator to `list()` or `tuple()`, the generator will run.