# Can I turn a generator object into a tuple without using "tuple()"?

Tags: python

It's possible to use the following code to create a list:

```
>>> [i+1 for i in(0,1,2)]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Can a similar thing be done with tuples?

```
>>> (i+1 for i in(0,1,2)),
(<generator object <genexpr> at 0x03A53CF0>,)
```

I would have expected `(1, 2, 3)` as the output.

I know you can do `tuple(i+1 for i in(0,1,2))`, but since you can do `[i+1 for i in(0,1,2)]`, I would expect a similar thing to be possible with tuples.

Comment: No, there are no tuple comprehensions.

Comment: No; parentheses actually aren't the syntax for a tuple, it's the *comma*. There's no "tuple comprehension", see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/16940293/3001761.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I know. `>>> 1,` outputs `(1,)`. I would still expect there to be a way to do that though.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In python 3 you can unpack a generator using `*`.

Here is an example:

```
>>> *(i+1 for i in (1,2,3)),
(2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: It's a cool trick but it's not explicit enough, and propably does not have the speed of a comprehension.

Comment: It __is__ a trick and a little less readable. I missed the `,` at the end when I tried it for the first time.

Comment: Do not be mistaken, this method is **not** faster than the obvious one: `tuple(i+1 for i in (1,2,3))`. It is just less readable and more confusing. --- It is also not some special syntax it is just unpacking the generator (it temporarily creates a list from it) into a new tuple (marked by the trailing coma).

Comment: @pabouk-Ukrainestaystrong, doesn't this method at least skip the call to `tuple`? How do you know it is not faster?