# Tuple() vs () for Tuple Comprehension & Tuple Creation

Tags: python, tuples

I understand I can create a tuple by these two methods:

```
tuple([1, 2, 3])
(1, 2, 3)
```

I'm trying to understand what exactly is happening here:

```
tuple( (x, x*x) for x in [1, 2, 3] )
```

the tuple constructor seems to want a list, but it doesn't seem like the following would produce a list

```
(x, x*x) for x in [1, 2, 3]
```

Also I'm wondering why this doesn't work:

```
( (x, x*x) for x in [1, 2, 3] )
```

With dictionaries it seems I can use either:

```
my_dict = dict()
my_dict = {}
```

but now I'm wondering if, like tuples, there's a difference.  Is `():tuple()` a different `::` relationship than `{}:dict()`?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940293/why-is-there-no-tuple-comprehension-in-python for some info

Comment: You got it wrong, Parenthesis have **nothing** to do with tuples. It's the **commas** that create tuples. `1,2,3` is the same as `(1,2,3)`. the outer parenthesis are just for grouping. The only case where you need parenthesis is the empty tuple `()`. The `tuple` constructor takes any iterable not just lists.

Comment: And you are feeding a generator expression which is iterable to the tuple() constructor. if you `print( ((x, x*x) for x in [1, 2, 3]) )` - you'll get somiething along `<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f847eccc0f8>` - putting this as iterable into `tuple(iterable)`creates the tuple by iterating the generator

Comment: There's no tuple comprehension, ((x, x*x) for x in [1, 2, 3]) this code is a generator comprehension. generator is a iterable object, i.e. range(5) is a generator.

Comment: Just to add to @Bakuriu comment. In a empty tuple the parentheses are the essential elements however this is not the case for one-element tuples and multiple-element tuples which can be defined like `1,` and `1,2,3`.

Answer (score 10):

Let's break down what's happening here. You're not wrong that the tuple constructor seems to want a list, but it would be more precise to say that the tuple constructor seems to want a list-like object. (to be specific, any iterable works)

This is a philosophy called as [Duck Typing](https://devopedia.org/duck-typing).

The saying goes as follows:

> If it walks like a duck, swims like a duck, and quacks like a duck,
>   then it probably is a duck.

So then, a list works

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 2]
tuple(a) #Output: (1, 2, 3, 2)
```

but so does a different iterable, such as a set

```
tuple(set(a)) #Output: (1, 2, 3)
```

So, tuple does not care whether the object it receives is a list, just that it should be able to iterate and get values from the object.

Now, The second part of the magic comes from something called list comprehension/generator expressions. They are iterables you can create which make it easy to write 1 liners that create a list or a generator expression respectively. More on the generator later, for now, it is sufficient to see how a list comprehension works.

A simple example of [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
[a for a in range(4)] #Output: [0, 1, 2, 3]
[a*a for a in range(4)] #output: [0, 1, 4, 9]
```

We see that they produce lists. So, can we feed them to a tuple constructor? Why not!

```
tuple([a for a in range(4)]) #Output: (0, 1, 2, 3)
tuple([a*a for a in range(4)]) #output: (0, 1, 4, 9)
```

Now, what about using the same expression but wrapping it in curved brackets instead?

```
(a for a in range(4)) #Output: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x000000FA4FDBE728>
```

You just created a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions)

They are essentially memory efficient on-demand iterables. (to be jargon specific, they have a yield and next , and only yield values as needed). Let's see it in action.

```
my_generator = (a for a in range(4)) #generator created. 
next(my_generator) #Outputs 0
next(my_generator) #Outputs 1
next(my_generator) #outputs 2
next(my_generator) #outputs 3
next(my_generator) #Raises StopIteration Error. The generator is exhausted.
```

We can see that we receive the same values as with our list comprehension. 
So, does a tuple accept something like a generator? Well, duck typing to the rescue! Absolutely!

```
tuple((a for a in range(4))) #Output: (0, 1, 2, 3)
```

Do i need the redundant parenthesis? Nope!

```
tuple(a for a in range(4)) #Output: (0, 1, 2, 3)
tuple(a*a for a in range(4)) #Output: (0, 1, 4, 9)
```

Now, what does this produce? `(x, x*x) for x in [1, 2, 3]`

Well, it is an expression, but let's get an idea of how it would look in a list comprehension instead

```
[(x, x*x) for x in [1, 2, 3]] #Output: [(1, 1), (2, 4), (3, 9)]
```

Ah, its a list of tuples? Can a generator do the same?

```
my_generator = ((x, x*x) for x in [1, 2, 3]) #<generator object <genexpr> at 0x000000FA4FD2DCA8>
next(my_generator) #Output: (1, 1)
next(my_generator) #Output: (2, 4)
next(my_generator) #Output: (3, 9)
next(my_generator) #Raises StopIteration
```

Yep, looks good. So its a generator, but its an iterable. Behaves like a duck anyways, doesn't it? So, the tuple constructor should work just fine!

```
tuple((x, x*x) for x in [1, 2, 3]) #Output: ((1, 1), (2, 4), (3, 9))
```

So, that wraps up everything. The parenthesis do not imply a tuple all the time, () are not reserved for tuples. We see here that they can be used for generator expressions as well! Similarly, the {} do not have to be tied to dictionaries always, something similar to list comprehension actually exists for dictionaries too! (Known as [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries))

I highly recommend going through the links for a more thorough explanation of the individual pieces that are working together here. Hope this helps!

Comment: One of the best answers I ever read on Stack Overflow, thanks for taking time writing this.