# How to divide tuples with tuples

Tags: python, tuples

```
tup1 = (100,200,300)
tup2 = (2,4,6)

tup = (x/y for x in tup1, y in tup2)
```

or

so i expected

```
tup = (50,50,50)
```

but there comes

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

for that comma

Comment: Even though [there are no tuple comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940293/why-is-there-no-tuple-comprehension-in-python) in Python, this wouldn't be syntactically valid for any type of generator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
tup = tuple(int(i/j) for i,j in zip(tup1, tup2))
```

**Output** :

```
(50,50,50)
```

**NOTE** :

1. When you do `(x/y for x in tup1, y in tup2)` you are trying to create a generator.
2. Again `(x/y for x in tup1, y in tup2)` is not valid double loop operation. You may have tried `(x/y for x in tup1 for y in tup2)` but again it would create a generator object and even if you mapped it to tuple format it would provide `(50.0, 25.0, 16.666666666666668, 100.0, 50.0, 33.333333333333336, 150.0, 75.0, 50.0)` - wrong because the way the double loop is operating.
3. You need `int(x/y)` in stead of only `i/j` because even though `i` and `j` are integers, the division operation would turn the result into a floating point.

Answer (score 1):

if You are going to work with big numbers, then a more effective way is to use Pandas or NumPy. It is easier and takes less time and resources.

```
#pandas
import pandas as pd

tup1 = (100,200,300)
tup2 = (2,4,6)

df = pd.DataFrame({'tup1': tup1, 'tup2': tup2} )
df    
    tup1    tup2
0   100     2
1   200     4
2   300     6

df['tup1'] / df['tup2']
0    50.0
1    50.0
2    50.0
dtype: float64


#numpy
import numpy as np

tup1 = (100,200,300)
tup2 = (2,4,6)

arr = np.array([tup1, tup2])
arr[0] / arr[1]

array([50., 50., 50.])
```