# Why does this yield a list and not a Tuple?

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to understand why my snippet of code ends up with the class "list" as opposed to a Tuple.

The way I'd like it to work is to open a CSV, check for the user/password header and use those to append to a tuple so that I can retrieve accounts by doing accounts[1], accounts[2]

It's important that the list of accounts is immutable to me, so I'm trying to end up with the class tuple.

```
# our csv file name
filename = "resources/accounts.csv"
with open(filename) as infile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
    accounts = []
    for row in reader:
        accounts.append((row['user'],row['password']))

print(type(accounts))
```

Comment: @AMC I believe it is, but is it more efficient than a list if you're looking for immutable items in said list?

Comment: Efficient in what sense?

Comment: @AMC I guess what's better practice? In what case would you use a list of tuples vs a tuples of tuples?

Comment: Since you’re looking for an immutable collection, a tuple of tuples sounds perfect to me.

Comment: By the way, I’m guessing that the CSV contains more columns than just the two you care about?

Comment: @AMC No, just the two :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206620/discussion-between-marcel-doe-and-amc).

Comment: Since it's immutable you can't append to a tuple.  You can only make a new tuple, which is more expensive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
accounts = []
for row in reader:
    accounts.append((row['user'],row['password']))
```

You're starting with an empty list `[]` and appending items to it, so you end up with a list. If you want a tuple you could convert the list to one at the end:

```
accounts = []
for row in reader:
    accounts.append((row['user'],row['password']))
accounts = tuple(accounts)
```

Better yet, [use a generator expression to create a tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940293/why-is-there-no-tuple-comprehension-in-python) from the get go. That way you avoid creating a temporary list just to throw it away.

```
with open(filename) as infile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
    accounts = tuple((row['user'], row['password']) for row in reader)
```

Comment: John, what's the difference between doing for row in reader and then accounts = tuple(etc) on a separate line vs doing it on the same line as you did?

Comment: See the link I added to my answer. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

As you already know a tuple is immutable. So you are correct in making `accounts` a list. If you want to store it as a tuple afterwards you can convert it like this:

```py
accounts = tuple(accounts)
```