# Trying to compute difference in a list from the first value of the list

Tags: python, arrays

Can someone help me write a python code that does this:

```
A = (1, 3, 5, 5, 2, 4, 6)
```

Basically, I want to create a variable that will take the first value in the array (in this case, 1), and spit out the difference of each element from that value:

eg. `1 = 1 = 0`, `3-1 = 2`, `5-1 = 0`, etc

to finally spit out a variable that has:

```
A = (0, 2, 4, 4, 1, 3, 5)
```

Comment: That's a tuple, not a list.

Comment: `[x - A[0] for x in A]`

Comment: So, you have a list ```A``` containing integers and you want to create another list ```B```, where ```B[i] = A[i] - A[0]```? Also @jordanm solution should work

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! This is not a code-writing or tutorial service, and we ask that you provide a [mcve] for your question, including _code_ for what you've tried based on your own research

Comment: `A = tuple(value-A[0] for value in A)`

Comment: Yep, that's the idea!

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a list in python is written with square brackets, like that:

```
l = [1, 3, 5, 5, 2, 4, 6]
```

To get your result there are many ways. One way would be list comprehensions, for example with

```
 [x - l[0] for x in l]
```

You can use map:

```
map(lambda x: x-l[0], l)
```

You could use a loop of many other ways.

Comment: The `map()` solution would produce a generator, so you would need to wrap it inside a `list()` call.

Answer (score 0):

This can be your solution.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,5,6]   # your list
>>> a_new = [i-a[0] for i in a]   # The output that you need.
>>> a_new
[0, 1, 2, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Basically, I want to create a variable that will take the first value in the array (in this case, 1), and spit out the difference of each element from that value:

The object `A` points to a `tuple` not a list or array.

Here's, how you should do it (One liner in Python) using [generator expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940293/why-is-there-no-tuple-comprehension-in-python):

```
A = (1, 3, 5, 5, 2, 4, 6)
print(tuple(i - li[0] for i in A))
```

Outputs:

```
(0, 2, 4, 4, 1, 3, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple program no need to use lambda and complicate things.

```
l = [1,3,4,6,5,3,6,8]
num = l[0]
l = [i-num for i in l]
print(l)
```

Use this if you do not want to include the first element -

```
l = [1,3,4,6,5,3,6,8]
num = l[0]
l = l[1:]
l = [i-num for i in l]
print(l)
```

`l[1:]` ----  this takes the values from index 1 to end from the list.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple question. People have been using lambda functions but don't worry, no need to complicate things here.

```
A = [1, 3, 5, 5, 2, 4, 6]
B = [num-A[0] for num in A]
```

This gives you the required array.