# Most efficient way of creating a tuple from list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am currently using a for loop with enumerate to extract from a list of tuples below:

`[(0, 'handle', 'VARCHAR(50)', 1, None, 1), (1, 'Firstname', 'TEXT', 1, None, 0), (2, 'Surname', 'TEXT', 1, None, 0), (3, 'Callname', 'TEXT', 1, None, 0), (4, 'Gender', 'INTEGER', 1, None, 0)]`

What i want is to end up with the following tuple `('handle', 'Firstname', 'Surname', 'Callname', 'Gender')`

What would be the most efficient way of accomplishing this without enumerating through them and creating a new tuple or is this the only way?

Answer (score 5):

Create a new tuple by enumerating through them:

```
tuple(t[1] for t in inputlist)
```

This uses a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) to pass each second element from the tuples in `inputlist` to the [`tuple()` constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple).

If you just need a *sequence* and a list would do, then use a list comprehension:

```
[t[1] for t in inputlist]
```

Lists fit arbitrary-length, ordered, homogenous data sets (such as you have here) better than do tuples, see [What's the difference between lists and tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626759/whats-the-difference-between-lists-and-tuples)

If *raw speed* is required and readability can be de-emphasised, use [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and [`operator.itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to move iteration and extraction to optimised C code:

```
from operator import itemgetter

labels_tup = tuple(map(itemgetter(1), inputlist))
labels_list = list(map(itemgetter(1), inputlist))
```

However, I'd *avoid* doing this unless extracting a bunch of strings out of a list of tuples is on a critical path and / or repeated a lot. Readability counts!

> without enumerating through them and creating a new tuple

You can't avoid this. You a) want one element from each tuple in a sequence, and b) need a tuple object as output, an immutable type. While you could write 5 separate statements indexing into `inputlist` to access each value, doing so would not be efficient, creates needlessly repeated code, and would break the moment your input doesn't have exactly 5 elements.

Demo:

```
>>> inputlist = [(0, 'handle', 'VARCHAR(50)', 1, None, 1), (1, 'Firstname', 'TEXT', 1, None, 0), (2, 'Surname', 'TEXT', 1, None, 0), (3, 'Callname', 'TEXT', 1, None, 0), (4, 'Gender', 'INTEGER', 1, None, 0)]
>>> tuple(t[1] for t in inputlist)
('handle', 'Firstname', 'Surname', 'Callname', 'Gender')
>>> [t[1] for t in inputlist]
['handle', 'Firstname', 'Surname', 'Callname', 'Gender']
```

Comment: Interestingly enough we came to the same conclusion so it's good my thoughts have been validated

Comment: @jamylak: in this case, it's faster. Not in all cases, however, for a [recent codereview answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/237906)  I could at best squeeze a few percentage points out of itertools (not added to that answer, it wasn't worth the trouble).

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [generator expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16940351/5735010).

```
print(tuple(i[1] for i in inputlist))
```

Or

```
t = tuple(i[1] for i in inputlist)
print(t)
```

Outputs:

```
('handle', 'Firstname', 'Surname', 'Callname', 'Gender')
```

A possible solution with `for` loop (Not recommended):

```
li = []
for i in inputlist:
    li.append(i[1])
print(tuple(li))
```

> What would be the most efficient way of accomplishing this without enumerating through them and creating a new tuple or is this the only way?

I am not sure why you want to avoid creating tuple but you don't need enumerate. May be the example given below can help:

```
def getElement(ndx):
    return inputlist[ndx][1]

# Get Second Element
print(getElement(2))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> data = [(0, 'handle', 'VARCHAR(50)', 1, None, 1), (1, 'Firstname', 'TEXT', 1, None, 0), (2, 'Surname', 'TEXT', 1, None, 0), (3, 'Callname', 'TEXT', 1, None, 0), (4, 'Gender', 'INTEGER', 1, None, 0)]
>>> tuple(map(itemgetter(1), data))
('handle', 'Firstname', 'Surname', 'Callname', 'Gender')
```

This seems to be the fastest in raw speed (only slightly however - since it keeps everything in `C` as much as possible), and I also do like the look of this as well. Of course you are still looping through the elements however.

Timings:

```
$ python3 -m timeit -s "data = [(0, 'handle', 'VARCHAR(50)', 1, None, 1), (1, 'Firstname', 'TEXT', 1, None, 0), (2, 'Surname', 'TEXT', 1, None, 0), (3, 'Callname', 'TEXT', 1, None, 0), (4, 'Gender', 'INTEGER', 1, None, 0)]; from operator import itemgetter;" "tuple(map(itemgetter(1), data))"
500000 loops, best of 5: 477 nsec per loop
$ python3 -m timeit -s "data = [(0, 'handle', 'VARCHAR(50)', 1, None, 1), (1, 'Firstname', 'TEXT', 1, None, 0), (2, 'Surname', 'TEXT', 1, None, 0), (3, 'Callname', 'TEXT', 1, None, 0), (4, 'Gender', 'INTEGER', 1, None, 0)]; from operator import itemgetter;" "tuple(t[1] for t in data)"
500000 loops, best of 5: 566 nsec per loop
$ python3 -m timeit -s "data = [(0, 'handle', 'VARCHAR(50)', 1, None, 1), (1, 'Firstname', 'TEXT', 1, None, 0), (2, 'Surname', 'TEXT', 1, None, 0), (3, 'Callname', 'TEXT', 1, None, 0), (4, 'Gender', 'INTEGER', 1, None, 0)]*1000; from operator import itemgetter;" "tuple(map(itemgetter(1), data))"
2000 loops, best of 5: 146 usec per loop
$ python3 -m timeit -s "data = [(0, 'handle', 'VARCHAR(50)', 1, None, 1), (1, 'Firstname', 'TEXT', 1, None, 0), (2, 'Surname', 'TEXT', 1, None, 0), (3, 'Callname', 'TEXT', 1, None, 0), (4, 'Gender', 'INTEGER', 1, None, 0)]*1000; from operator import itemgetter;" "tuple(t[1] for t in data)"
1000 loops, best of 5: 212 usec per loop
```