# Tuple comprehension is generating unexpected output

Tags: python, tuples

```
x=(y for y in range(100) if y%2==0 and y%5==0)
print(x)
```

This is giving output like -

```
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x00000222B1C3CC80>
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a `tuple comprehension` in python. What you have is what it is telling you it is: a `generator` object. You can iterate over this if you want.

Comment: A "tuple comprehension" would be this to turn this generator into a tuple through the `tuple` constructor: `tuple(y for y in ...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tuple comprehension is not a thing. Check [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940293/why-is-there-no-tuple-comprehension-in-python) to understand why.

Do this instead:

```
x = tuple(y for y in range(100) if y%2==0 and y%5==0)
```

This uses the `tuple()` constructor to make a tuple from the generator object. You can use this constructor to make a tuple from elements yielded by an iterator or iterable object. So, this code works because generator objects can be used as iterators.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you can do

```
x=tuple(y for y in range(100) if y%2==0 and y%5==0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tuple()` function to cast it.

```py
x = (y for y in range(100) if y % 2 == 0 and y % 5 == 0)
print(tuple(x))
# (0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90)
```

Comment: btw There is no `casting` in python. Your example is of a conversion.