# How can I take a variable number of arguments into a function and use them as indices?

Tags: python, function, tuples, indices

Here is an example without a function:

```
my_string = "tremendeous"
my_tuples = (my_string[3], my_string[7])
```

Now if I want to generalize it, I'm lost as to how I can handle making the tuples variable in size?

What if the user wants 1 index, or maybe 3 indices or maybe 5 indices?

```
def doIt(my_string, *indices):
   
   my_tuples = (my_string[indices_1], my_string[indices_2] .... my_string[indices_n])

   return my_tuples
```

Someone could call: doIt("tremendeous", 3) or doIt("tremendeous", 3, 5) or doIt("tremendeous", 0, 3, 4, 4)

I know that I can use the "*" to take multiple arguments, but how can I feed a variable number of argument to my_tuples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
In [10]: def doit(s, *indices):
    ...:     return tuple(s[i] for i in indices)

In [11]: doit("tremendous", 1, 3, 5, 7)
Out[11]: ('r', 'm', 'n', 'o')
```

See this [SO question about "tuple comprehensions"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940293/why-is-there-no-tuple-comprehension-in-python).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to create a function that fetches items from an iterable (your string) with the given indexes, pass the indexes to the function by unpacking the passed args into positional arguments

```
from operator import itemgetter

def foo(my_string, *indices):
    return itemgetter(*indices)(my_string)

my_string = "tremendeous"
foo(my_string, 3, 7)  # ('m', 'e')
```